# Select a value in text file

Tags: cmd

I have a table of +500000 rows in a text file and I need to select those rows which follow a criteria. Its head column is "Quantity" and the value I want to get is 12 (integer value).
I use the Windows command line.

[There are four columns. In this example, you can see the value "12", but there are more than twelve values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LWYu.png)

Comment: show us a few lines of your text file.

Comment: I uploaded a sample of my text file

Comment: so ypu want each line, that has a `12` in it's second column (columns separated by a space)?

Comment: Yes. Data is separated by space. 
From this table, I have to select Quantity = 12, then get all the rows which have that value (I will delete them)

Comment: Use regular expression and you'll have two problems. Hint: `sed` and/or `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to do that by cmd.

You can use **findstr** command to find some specyficed strings in a text file, but cmd cant recognize column.

Answer (score 0):

according to the comments, you want to delete each line, that has a `12` as second value (word). This can be done even with `findstr`s crippled REGEX support, which makes it a simple one-line command:

```
findstr  /rvc:"^[^ ]* 12 " input.txt>output.txt
```

`findstr` switches: `r`: Regex-Support, `v` exclude findings, `c`: "literal" (needed because of the spaces)

REGEX:
`^`: Start of the line
`[^ ]`: any character (`[]` that is not (`^`) a space ()
`*`: maybe more of such
`12`: space-12-space

Results in finding any line, that starts with one or more non-space characters, followed by a space, a `12` and another space. (or ignoring them with `/v`)

Record of my `cmd` session:

```
>type t.txt
123.54 12 1 5
123.52 12 1 4
12.52 12 1 3
423.05 11 2 4
41 10 1 6
12 22 33 4
411,26 5 12 4


>findstr  /rvc:"^[^ ]* 12 " t.txt>output.txt

>type output.txt
423.05 11 2 4
41 10 1 6
12 22 33 4
411,26 5 12 4


>findstr  /rc:"^[^ ]* 12 " t.txt>output.txt

>type output.txt
123.54 12 1 5
123.52 12 1 4
12.52 12 1 3

>
```

Comment: I saw the output, but still has 12

Comment: added a log for proving.